# How to change Liferay 6.2 site-navigation collapse behavior?

Tags: javascript, liferay, portlet, navbar, dock

That's it, by default, liferay main navigation is being collapsed to dockbar, wich is hidden for not admin users in my solution. I tryed hooking the dockbar and deleting the collapse icon, but site-navigation keeps hiding on window resize.

Any ideas please?

P.D: I saw this post:
- [Move collapsed menu button from the dockbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27701503/move-collapsed-menu-button-from-the-dockbar/30569741#30569741)

Where the problem is solved, but as I mention there, I think it's not a "stylish" way of solving this problem and it's could give me more problems.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Are you using the classic theme or your own custom theme? You wish to have a non responsive menu navigation?
I wait for a response, but in any case we have to switch off the bootstrap responsive part and hook a particular dockbar part.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I'm customizing classic theme (not a good Idea I know..). I still wish a responsive menu of course. The problem is that I need to hide the dockbar to non-admin users but the site navigation is collapsing to a "hamburger icon" that's placed in the dockbar. That behavior isn't the desired, non-admin users won't have navigation when accesing the site from small screen devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the fly i could tell you how to solve it the toggle button in case of no dockbar presence.

On your custom theme based on classic one you have to customize navigation.vm and insert the code to have the hamburger icon close to the navigation.

(The code is not tested)

```
<nav class="$nav_css_class navbar site-navigation" id="navigation" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-inner">

        #* start toogle hamburger menu *#

        <a class="visible-phone brand btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navigation">
            <i class="icon-reorder"></i>
            #language ("main-menu")
        </a>

        #* end *#

        <div class="collapse nav-collapse">
            <ul aria-label="#language ("site-pages")" class="nav nav-collapse" role="menubar">
                #foreach ($nav_item in $nav_items)
                        #set ($nav_item_attr_selected="")
                        #set ($nav_item_attr_has_popup="")
                        #set ($nav_item_caret="")
                        #set ($nav_item_css_class="lfr-nav-item")
                        #set ($nav_item_link_css_class="")

        #*continue...*#
```